# Swift fatal error while scrolling

Tags: xcode, swift, crash

again.

I have a problem with my little project.

It runs but if i try to scroll down it crashes!

The part of code with the fatal error is this:

```
  func fontForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIFont? {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let familyName = familyNames[indexPath.row]
        let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first! as String
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is in line 4.

Comment: What is `familyName`?  And what does the error say?

Comment: It's a constant with a font name (taken from the array familyNames for the value of each row. The error is this: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that casting is failing, wrap it in if let

```
if let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first as? String{
   return UIFont(name: fontName, size: cellPointSize)
}
```

Comment: this error now: "Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?"

Comment: btw, familyName is an array?

Comment: No, familyName is a constant. It is the name for a cell identifier. This is its declaration:     private let familyCell = "familyName"

Comment: the error says: Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: @iGermanos hey, 1 question, swift 2 or swift 1.2? (xcode 7 or xcode 6.4)

Answer (score 0):

```
let fontName = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first
```

as String!
or

```
let fontName : String! = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName).first
```